# When exactly is "just before hitting the ground"?

Tags: kinematics, collision, projectile

So it just hit me, "When is just before"? Cos just before could be a second ago or half a second ago or a tenth of a second ago and so on. So when? And do the final velocity formulas put this into consideration?

Comment: The relevant mathematical concepts are “[infinitesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal)” and “[limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics))”. “Just before” is smaller than any finite amount of time before.

Answer (score 5):

This is in the context of the motion of a particle under the influence of gravity. "Just before" means the instant when the particle is at the height of the ground, but before any interaction between the particle and the ground has taken place. The reason for this wording is because the kinematic formulas we use don't account for the interaction between the particle and the ground, so once this interaction begins these formulas no longer apply, but we'd still like to answer questions like "What speed does the particle have when it first makes contact with the ground?"